# How to get signed in user PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert data to mySql db with php. When the person is logged in, I want him or her to choose the day and message. Later on, I want to be able to see what user entered what message.

The code for when someone is logged in and answers the form:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggein"]) || $_SESSION["loggein"] == false) {
  echo "done";
  }
 ?>
 <h2>you have logged in</h2>
 <form class="" action="Insert.php" method="post">
   Day: <input type="text" name="day" value="">
   message: <input type="textbox" name="message" value="" rows="10">
   <input type="submit" name="" value="Send">
 </form>

insert.php

$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['message']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST[get_current_user($username)]);

$stmt = "INSERT INTO userInfo (day, message, username) VALUES('$day', '$message', '$username')";
if(empty($day) || empty($message)){
  echo "fyll i tbx revyn";
} else {
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
    echo "added";
    header('Location: success.php', true, 303);
        exit;
  }else {
    echo "Error: " .mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}
```

The username field ends up empty when I select all from the userInfo table. I want it to automatically insert the username of the person that is logged in and fills in the form. How can I do that? 
I have no problem with the person logging in and answering the form, the only problem is that the username field ends up empty in te userInfor table.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like MD5 or SHA1/2.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `$_REQUEST[get_current_user($username)]` to do?  Why?

Comment: To add to what @David says, if the username is in the session you can start the session on the page then use something like `$username = $_SESSION['username'];` if that's what you want to do.